# Кастомное окно заползает под "пуск"

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть стиль окна:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
        <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <shell:WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0,0,0,-1"
                                    CornerRadius="0"
                                    ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                                    CaptionHeight="50"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="Journal Reader V3"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border Name="MAIN_BORDER" BorderThickness="2"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowColorBrush}"
                            Background="{StaticResource WindowColorBrush}">
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static shell:SystemParameters2.Current}, Path=WindowResizeBorderThickness}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Name="TopRow" Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Background="{StaticResource WindowColorBrush}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="290"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                           Text="Journal Reader V3"
                                           FontSize="36"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Foreground="White"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight"/>
                                <View:PortControlView Grid.Column="2"
                                                      Grid.Row="0"
                                                      Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                      shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"></View:PortControlView>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="4"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                                            shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                    <Button Command="{Binding MinimizeCommand}"
                                            Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}"
                                            ToolTip="Свернуть">
                                        <Grid Margin="2">
                                            <Path Fill="White"
                                                  Stroke="White"
                                                  StrokeThickness="3">
                                                <Path.Data>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,14.5"
                                                                  EndPoint="16,14.5"></LineGeometry>
                                                </Path.Data>
                                            </Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}"
                                            Command="{Binding MaxNormCommand}"
                                            ToolTip="Восстановить">
                                        <Grid Margin="2">
                                            <Path Fill="White"
                                                  Stroke="White"
                                                  StrokeThickness="3">
                                                <Path.Data>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,1.5"
                                                                  EndPoint="16,1.5"/>
                                                </Path.Data>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Path Fill="White"
                                                  Stroke="White"
                                                  StrokeThickness="1">
                                                <Path.Data>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.5,0"
                                                                  EndPoint="0.5,16"></LineGeometry>
                                                </Path.Data>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Path Fill="White"
                                                  Stroke="White"
                                                  StrokeThickness="1">
                                                <Path.Data>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="15.5,0"
                                                                  EndPoint="15.5,16"></LineGeometry>
                                                </Path.Data>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Path Fill="White"
                                                  Stroke="White"
                                                  StrokeThickness="1">
                                                <Path.Data>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,15.5"
                                                                  EndPoint="16,15.5"></LineGeometry>
                                                </Path.Data>
                                            </Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonCloseStyle}"
                                            Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
                                            ToolTip="Закрыть">
                                        <Grid Margin="2">
                                            <Path Fill="White"
                                                  Stroke="White"
                                                  StrokeThickness="2">
                                                <Path.Data>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0"
                                                                  EndPoint="16,16"></LineGeometry>
                                                </Path.Data>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Path Fill="White"
                                                  Stroke="White"
                                                  StrokeThickness="2">
                                                <Path.Data>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,16"
                                                                  EndPoint="16,0"></LineGeometry>
                                                </Path.Data>
                                            </Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <shell:WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0"
                                    CornerRadius="0"
                                    ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                                    CaptionHeight="57"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="TopRow" Property="Height" Value="57"></Setter>

                            <Setter TargetName="MAIN_BORDER" Property="Padding" Value="7"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Но при разворачивании окна происходит следующее:

[image: нормальное состояние]
[image: пуск справа]
[image: пуск сверху]

Использую .Net 4.0, но тестировал различные стили для .Net 4.5 с данного сайта, происходит тоже самое...

Comment: Вы не правильно пишите стили. Посмотрите на готовые реализации, как пример `MahApps`, его исходный код есть на гитхабе.

Comment: @Birdy: не успел добавить код и картинки, а вы уже ответили...

Comment: Дело в том что когда-то, тоже были такие проблемы.

Comment: @Birdy: И как удалось побороть?